# sort numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I am trying to sort the below code by unable to

```
@image_tags_cache['imagetags'].each do |tag|
puts #{tag}
```

It prints the following

```
57
224_90_345.09.1.0
55
124_90_345.09.1.0
```

But when I am trying to sort, I get errors

```
@image_tags_cache['imagetags'].sort.each do |tag|
```

ArgumentError - comparison of NilClass with String failed:

```
@image_tags_cache['imagetags'].to_i.sort.each do |tag|
```

NoMethodError - undefined method `to_i' for #
Did you mean?  to_s
               to_a
               to_h:

```
@image_tags_cache['imagetags'].to_s.sort.each do |tag|
```

NoMethodError - undefined method `sort' for #String:0x00007f993c0c1c50>:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `@image_tags_cache['imagetags']` includes `nil` values. Calling `to_i` might not make sense, because it would translate `nil` to `0` and that `0` values would be printed too.

I suggest to instead remove the `nil` values by calling `compact` on the array first:

```
@image_tags_cache['imagetags'].compact.sort.each do |tag|
  puts tag
end
```